# `docker build` command hangs for a very long time, other commands work fine

Tags: docker

Simple question:  After using Docker for about a week, my `docker build` command gets bogged down and hangs (before anything executes) for about a minute.  After staying in this hanging state, it will execute the `docker build` command with no issues at all and at at the expected speed.

Other Docker commands (like `docker run`) do not suffer from this "hanging" issue.

Docker Installation info:

```
Version 18.06.1-ce-win73
Channel: stable
```

Things I have tried:

- `docker system prune` - This does clear up space, but doesn't speed up my `docker build` command
- Reinstalling Docker on my machine - This does fix the issue, but it reappeared after about a week of using Docker again.

Does anyone else suffer from this issue?

Comment: Do you wipe out docker images that you don't use anymore?

Comment: @aydinugur, yes. I use the `docker system prune` command to delete unused images.  I also will manually delete images I don't use

Comment: Maybe the problem with cache? For the first time, it can take much more time than next builds

Comment: I'd guess, your build context is simply too large. The whole content of the build context directory (except items mentioned in `.dockerignore`) is sent to the server before the actual build starts.

Comment: @Henry, the issue goes away after a reinstall of Docker.  Wouldn't that indicate it's not an issue with the build context?  As a test, I ran a `docker build` with a very simple Dockerfile and I still have the issue.

Comment: I think the author should provide more information about the problem!

Comment: @Henry's comment here was the answer for me - a large build context and slow filetransfer over WSL explains why my build was taking so long to output anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here was the the issue:

The very first line of my Dockerfile (the `FROM` command) was failing.  The "hanging" was caused by a timeout during the attempt to download the base image.  I was attempting to download the base image from a location that I needed to set a proxy on my machine for.

So I was mistaken in my original post: The `Docker build` command wasn't running as expected.  It was failing to download the base image due to a missing proxy setting.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I solved it moving the Dockerfile to an empty folder, then I executed the `docker build` command and worked perfectly.

On some other forums people created a `.dockerignore` file including the any call to git and many other files, but that approach didn't work for me.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 1):

My situation was solved by the hint [from Fco's answer above.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56086345/5898327)

Basically, I was not mindful of my build context size. I had a git submodule that gathered a lot of data after usage that was bloating the build context.
The solution was to include this (and other directories and subfolders not essential to the build) in the aforementioned `.dockerignore` file.

That would also explain why copying the Dockerfile to a different directory does the trick.

Answer (score -1):

2 reasons:

1.If you are building many dockers for hours ..please restart your router if possible as sometimes due to heavy data packets movement the router collapses.

2.Increase RAM ,CPU and Swap of docker engine and restart docker and try to build again.